# How to sort a list but keep related together

Tags: sorting

I have an object with fields "ID", "PRICE", "QUANTITY" & "LINKED_ID", and "ID" is the unique key, now I'm going to sort these objects by either "ID", "PRICE" or "QUANTITY", but needs to keep the ones with the same "LINKED_ID" together

For example, i got the following data

```
ID    PRICE    QUANTITY    LINKED_ID
1     10       5           LID00001
2     12       4           LID00001
3     9        6           LID00002
4     11       8           LID00003
```

When sort in "PRICE", I wanna get the below result

```
ID    PRICE    QUANTITY    LINKED_ID
3     9        6           LID00002
1     10       5           LID00001
2     12       4           LID00001
4     11       8           LID00003
```

Record of ID#1 & ID#2 must be kept together, as they have the same LINKED_ID

Comment: Either in C++, Java, .NET or Delphi will be fine

Comment: I don't see a definition of what *object* is, or what kind of "list* you're keeping them in. Your question as currently stated is far too vague.

Comment: how would you rank this with the example: id = 5, price 10, quantity indifferent, linkedId = LID00003 ? And if the id = 4 would be priced 12 as well?

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary as it has the same linkedId, this new record will follow id#4 due to LID00003

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can implement the Comparable interface and override the compareTo() method.

```
class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject >{
  //Properties
  //Getter and setter for properties
  public int compareTo(Fruit compareFruit) {
   //Your sorting logic goes here
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not asking for how to implement a comparer but the algorithm